# Upgrading Windows Server 2000 Terminal Server to 2003 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services, windows-server-2000, licensing

I have a Windows 2000 Terminal Server and I need to upgrade to Windows Server 2003 R2. What path do I need to take to do an in-place upgrade? My only choice is an in-place upgrade in this scenario. Do I use a Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard CD or is there a special Windows Server 2003 Terminal Server CD or what OS or Path do I take? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

There is no special version of Windows Server 2003 for Terminal Services-- it's a single product. (Obviously, the "Edition" that you need-- Standard, Enterprise, etc, would be dictated by your requirements.)

The OS itself will upgrade in-place without issue. I'd be most concerned about the Terminal Services Licensing service, which you might be running on this machine (but could be running on another). Per Microsoft, [a Windows 2000 Terminal Services Licensing Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823313) will upgrade in-place to Windows Server 2003 Terminal Services Licensing.

Comment: So when I do an in-place upgrade of the OS, will it automatically in-place upgrade the Windows Server Terminal Services Licensing Server?

Comment: Keep in mind, you can only do an in-place upgrade of to a 32 bit version of Windows Server 2003 R2.  This keeps your RAM limit to 4 GB.  If you wanted to go to 64 bit, you'd have to do a clean install, but then you could access far more RAM and have far more users per server.